# Finding a derivative using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $R$. Define $$F(x) = \int_{a}^{x} f(t)(x - t) dt.$$

Evaluate $F''(x)$.

---

**My Working**

I know that, if $$F(x) = \int_{a}^{x} f(t) dt,$$ then by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, $$F'(x) = (1)f(x) - (0)f(a) = f(x)$$

However, when I use the same idea for the integral in the question, I get $$F'(x) = (1)f(x)(x - x) - (0)f(a)(x - a) = 0$$

---

**The Answer**

$$F''(x) = f(x)$$

---

I did not go on to evaluate $F''(x)$ as I know I must have gone wrong somewhere since my $F'(x)$ is a constant.

Why can I not simply take "$f(t)(x - t)$" to be the new function? Any intuitive explanations as to where I have gone wrong will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You need https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule because the integrand depends on x as well.

Comment: @MartinR Hello. Thank you for your comment! That looks complicated and I have not learnt that yet, but I have looked through the rule and it seems that, with regards to the question, for my $F'(x)$, I am simply missing the integral of the partial derivative of my integrand with respect to $x$, would that be correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$F(x)=\int_{a}^{x}f(t)(x-t)dt$$
$$=x\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt-\int_{a}^{x}tf(t)dt.$$

Thus by FTC and the product rule we have $$F'(x)=\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt+xf(x)-xf(x)=\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt$$

And applying FTC once again we obtain $$F''(x)=f(x)$$ as required.

---

Using the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule), that is

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{g(x)}^{h(x)}f(x,t) dt=f(x,h(x)) h'(x)-f(x,g(x))g'(x)+\int_{g(x)}^{h(x)}f_{x}(x,t)dt$$

we have $$F'(x)=f(x)(x-x)+\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt=\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt$$ and again $$F''(x)=f(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

Rearrange to write:
$$F(x)=x\int_{a}^{x} f(t) dt -\int_{a}^{x} tf(t)dt$$
D. w.r.t. $x$ using Lebnitz gives
$$F'(x)=1 \int_{a}^{x} f(t) dt+x f(x)-xf(x)= \int_{a}^{x} f(t) dt$$
Again D.w.r.t. $x$ we get
$$F''(x)=F(x)$$